# Is my javascript brute force recursion Sudoku solver running out of memory?

Tags: javascript, memory, recursion, sudoku

I wrote a javascript program to solve sudoku. It seems to be working but then it suddenly stops.
[Console shows that it is working but suddenly stops for no reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqsce.png)

Is this the reason? : [(Timeline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2IXe.png) I am new to javascript, what can i do to fix it?

How do i fix this? thanks!

Here is the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var game = [
      [0, 0, 9, 0, 5, 7, 0, 6, 0],
      [0, 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 5, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 1, 7, 2],
      [4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 9, 3],
      [6, 3, 7, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 8, 0],
      [0, 5, 0, 2, 9, 0, 4, 0, 0]
    ];

    function solve(x, y, g) {
      var nextx;
      var nexty = y;
      if (x < 9 || y < 9) {
        if (g[x][y] == 0) {
          for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            g[x][y] = i;
            if (check(x, y, i, g) == true) {
              if (x < 8) {
                nextx = x + 1;
              } else {
                nexty = y + 1;
                nextx = 0;
              }
              console.log(x + ' ' + y + ' ' + i + ' ' + g[x][y]);
              solve(nextx, nexty, g);
            } else {
              if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (x < 8) {
            nextx = x + 1;
          } else {
            nexty = y + 1;
            nextx = 0;
          }
          console.log(x + ' ' + y + ' ' + 'b' + ' ' + g[x][y]);
          solve(nextx, nexty, g);
          return;
        }
      } else {
        if (checkall(g) == true) {
          for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            document.write(g[i] + '</br>');
          };
        } else {
          document.write("can't solve");
        }
      }
    }

    function check(x, y, i, g) {
      var tempx = 0;
      var tempy = 0;
      var tempb = 0;
      var a, b;

      for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (g[x][j] == i) {
          tempx = tempx + 1;
        }
        if (g[j][y] == i) {
          tempy = tempy + 1;
        }
      }

      if (x < 3) {
        a = 0;
      }
      if (x < 6) {
        a = 3;
      }
      if (x < 9) {
        a = 6;
      }
      if (y < 3) {
        b = 0;
      }
      if (y < 6) {
        b = 3;
      }
      if (y < 9) {
        b = 6;
      }

      for (c = a; c < a + 3; c++) {
        for (d = b; d < b + 3; d++) {
          if (g[a][b] == i) {
            tempb = tempb + 1;
          }
        }
      }

      if (tempx > 1 || tempy > 1 || tempb > 1) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }

    }

    function checkall(g) {
      var temp1 = 0;
      var temp2 = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
          for (var y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            if (g[x][y] == i) {
              temp1 = temp1 + 1;
            }
            if (g[y][x] == i) {
              temp2 = temp2 + 1;
            }
          };
          if (temp1 > 1 || temp2 > 1) {
            return false;
          } else {
            temp1 = 0;
            temp2 = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      return true
    }

    solve(0, 0, game);
  </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but why don't you make the array 'game' and object and the functions solve and check methods of the 'game' object.

Comment: I am new to objects, will that help in any way?

Comment: It will mean you can wrap up everything in the object encapsulating all the functions and not having to pass around the data to everything.

Comment: What are you expecting to see from your code?  As far as I can tell you do not write anything to the DOM, it will run through the logic and do nothing with the results.  Get use to using try and catch in your functions to catch any errors and report.  The functions look ok, you just need to do something to publish the results.

Comment: @SPlatten eventually, when it reaches the final cell and everything is correct, document.write(g[i] + '</br>'); should output the solution. problem is it stops after a few iterations at (1,2) for no reason, or no reason i know of.

Comment: this seems to do a loot of consol.log. Does browsers allow this so freely ?

Comment: Sudoko's complexity is too high for brute-force it with a js program, you'll run into a stack overflow issue (which makes this question a perfect fit for this site ;-) ! ). Even if you are less 'brutal', and take, line by line, all the permutation of [1..9], you have 362880 permutations per line, so 362880^9  = 1e50 permutations for the whole grid !!! (you might improve that a lot by cuting branches early... to which extent ??)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the responses returned from functions:

```
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
```

Will fail and div will be 'undefined' because you have no opening div tag in your example with the 'output' id.

If you add try / catch clauses to your functions you will see errors reported.

I can see that you aren't actually using the 'div' in your code.

I've just modified your code slightly as I don't get any errors when I run it:

```
    <html>
    <body>
      <script>
        var game = [
          [0, 0, 9, 0, 5, 7, 0, 6, 0],
          [0, 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 5, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 1, 7, 2],
          [4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 9, 3],
          [6, 3, 7, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 8, 0],
          [0, 5, 0, 2, 9, 0, 4, 0, 0]
        ];
        var intNestedCalls = 0;
        function solve(x, y, g) {
          var nextx;
          var nexty = y;
          intNestedCalls++; //Count numer of nested calls
          if (x < 9 || y < 9) {
            if (g[x][y] == 0) {
              for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                g[x][y] = i;
                if (check(x, y, i, g) == true) {
                  if (x < 8) {
                    nextx = x + 1;
                  } else {
                    nexty = y + 1;
                    nextx = 0;
                  }
                  console.log(x + ' ' + y + ' ' + i + ' ' + g[x][y]);
                  solve(nextx, nexty, g);
                } else {
                  if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
    //Break here so we drop out and exit the function              
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            } else {
              if (x < 8) {
                nextx = x + 1;
              } else {
                nexty = y + 1;
                nextx = 0;
              }
              console.log(x + ' ' + y + ' ' + 'b' + ' ' + g[x][y]);
              solve(nextx, nexty, g);
    //No need to return here, fall through and exit normally
    //        return;                  
            }
          } else {
            if (checkall(g) == true) {
              for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                document.write(g[i] + '</br>');
              };
            } else {
              document.write("can't solve");
            }
          }
          intNestedCalls--; //Update nested call counter
        }
        function check(x, y, i, g) {
          var tempx = 0;
          var tempy = 0;
          var tempb = 0;
          var a, b;
          for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (g[x][j] == i) {
              tempx = tempx + 1;
            }
            if (g[j][y] == i) {
              tempy = tempy + 1;
            }
          }
          if (x < 3) {
            a = 0;
          }
          if (x < 6) {
            a = 3;
          }
          if (x < 9) {
            a = 6;
          }
          if (y < 3) {
            b = 0;
          }
          if (y < 6) {
            b = 3;
          }
          if (y < 9) {
            b = 6;
          }
          for (c = a; c < a + 3; c++) {
            for (d = b; d < b + 3; d++) {
              if (g[a][b] == i) {
                tempb = tempb + 1;
              }
            }
          }
          if (tempx > 1 || tempy > 1 || tempb > 1) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
        function checkall(g) {
          var temp1 = 0;
          var temp2 = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
              for (var y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                if (g[x][y] == i) {
                  temp1 = temp1 + 1;
                }
                if (g[y][x] == i) {
                  temp2 = temp2 + 1;
                }
              };
              if (temp1 > 1 || temp2 > 1) {
                return false;
              } else {
                temp1 = 0;
                temp2 = 0;
              }
            }
          }
          return true;
        }
        solve(0, 0, game);    
    alert("Complete!");    
      </script>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I do not see any output at all except the complete! alert after a short period.

The logic will never get to your 'document.write' instructions because x and y your logic will only get to the write statements if x AND y are >= 9.

Should your test be:

```
    if ( x < 9 && y < 9 ) {
```

Comment: that was testing from before i accidentaly left there. it doesn't do anything.

Comment: wont this output the result?
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.write(g[i] + '</br>');
};

Comment: No because your logic isn't correct and it will never get there!

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time commenting on this site but it IS possible to run a brute force sudoku solver in js because there isnt 1e50 possible permutations because this includes situations where every number could be a 1. Actually there are 6670903751057913937920 solutions to a sudoku. That number just got 1e27 times smaller. But a program running a brute force wont run even close to that number. Instead it will run it usually at most 10000 times before you have a solved sudoku because of the given values. Here is the code to one I made and the reason why it stops is because the sudoku hints you have plugged in dont have a solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>

            var board = [
            [5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
            [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
            [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
            [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
            [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
            [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
            [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
            [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
            [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9],
            ];

        function solve(a){
            var zeros = [];
            for(i=0;i<Math.pow(a.length,2);i++){
                var x = i%a.length;
                var y = (i-x)/a.length;
                if(board[y][x]===0){
                    zeros.push([x,y,1]);
                }
            }
            var count = 0;
            var total = [];
            for(i=0;i<zeros.length;i++){
                console.log("s");
                count+=1;
                var x = zeros[i][0];
                if(zeros[i][2]<board.length+1){
                    for(j=zeros[i][2];j<board.length+1;j++){
                        if(check(x,y,j)==true){
                            a[y][x] = j;
                            zeros[i][2] = j + 1;
                            j=board.length+1;
                        }else if(check(x,y,j)==false && j===board.length){
                            j=board.length+1;
                            zeros[i][2] = 1;
                            i-=2;
                            a[y][x] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    zeros[i][2] = 1;
                    a[y][x] = 0;
                    i-=2;
                }
                for(j=0;j<board.length;j++){
                    console.log(board[j][0],board[j][1],board[j][2],board[j][3],board[j][4],board[j][5],board[j][6],board[j][7],board[j][8]);
                }
                console.log(count);
            }
        }

        function check(a,b,c){
            var right = true;
            for(k=0;k<board.length;k++){
                if(board[b][k]===c || board[k][a]===c){
                    right = false;
                }
            }
            for(k=0;k<Math.sqrt(board.length);k++){
                for(l=0;l<Math.sqrt(board.length);l++){
                    if(board[Math.sqrt(board.length)*Math.floor(b/Math.sqrt(board.length))+k][Math.sqrt(board.length)*Math.floor(a/Math.sqrt(board.length))+l]==c){
                        right = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(right === true){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        solve(board);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```